# Equivalent Math.toRadians() using kotlin.math

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I would like to know if there is an equivalent Math.toRadians in kotlin.

I need to calculate distance between 2 locations on earth sphere.

Got this haversine formula from this gist

https://gist.github.com/jferrao/cb44d09da234698a7feee68ca895f491

```
internal class DistanceCalculator(private val lat: Double, private val lon: Double) {

    companion object {
        const val earthRadiusKm: Double = 6372.8
    }

    /**
     * Haversine formula. Giving great-circle distances between two points on a sphere from their longitudes and latitudes.
     * It is a special case of a more general formula in spherical trigonometry, the law of haversines, relating the
     * sides and angles of spherical "triangles".
     *
     * https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#Java
     *
     * @return Distance in kilometers
     */
    fun haversine(destination: Geo): Double {
        val dLat = Math.toRadians(destination.lat - this.lat);
        val dLon = Math.toRadians(destination.lon - this.lon);
        val originLat = Math.toRadians(this.lat);
        val destinationLat = Math.toRadians(destination.lat);


        val a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2), 2.toDouble()) + Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2), 2.toDouble()) * Math.cos(originLat) * Math.cos(destinationLat);
        val c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        return earthRadiusKm * c;
    }

}
```

I need to use it without any java lib in an sdk from a kmm project.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about just write it yourself? It's an extremely simple function.

Comment: Also note that the haversine formula won't give you exact results because the Earth is not exactly spherical, it's a bit squashed.

Comment: Also, you might like to consider a library for units of measurement, such as [KotUniL](https://github.com/vsirotin/si-units) (other libraries also exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick(reverse as well)

```
import kotlin.math.PI
        
fun toRadians(deg: Double): Double = deg / 180.0 * PI

fun toDegrees(rad: Double): Double = rad * 180.0 / PI
```